# Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (da)

Tags: content-management

i'm suddenly experiencing an error, i get the following stacktrace and am clueless on how to fix it. I belive it to be an editor error but where to start?

```
    Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (da)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (da)

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[InvalidOperationException: Item must have more than 1 version in the default language (da)]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsTrue(Boolean condition, String message) +57
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.EnsureFallbackVersion(Item rootItem) +252
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, TemplateID templateId) +142
   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Utilities.LanguageFallbackDataService.GetDescendantsByTemplateWithFallback(Item rootItem, String templateId) +117
   SCommerce.Website.Code.Infobar.NotificationViewModelFactory.GetActiveNotifications() in D:\jenkins\sitecore-patch-tollgate\co\src\SCommerce.Website.Code\Infobar\NotificationViewModelFactory.cs:69
   SCommerce.Website.Code.Infobar.NotificationViewModelFactory.GetNotificationViewModels() in D:\jenkins\sitecore-patch-tollgate\co\src\SCommerce.Website.Code\Infobar\NotificationViewModelFactory.cs:40
   SCommerce.Website.SCom.Renderings.Layout.Controllers.SCommerceLayoutController.SetInfoBars() in D:\jenkins\sitecore-patch-tollgate\co\src\SCommerce.Website\SCom\Renderings\Layout\Controllers\SCommerceLayoutController.cs:225
   SCommerce.Website.SCom.Renderings.Layout.Controllers.SCommerceLayoutController.Main() in D:\jenkins\sitecore-patch-tollgate\co\src\SCommerce.Website\SCom\Renderings\Layout\Controllers\SCommerceLayoutController.cs:200
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +209
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +462
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +462
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +629
```

Comment: Did you remove all the versions of the item from your default language? Are you able to add an item version back?

Comment: It seems a folder was somehow corrupted, republishing it didn't help, nor changing it and republishing it.
We then took the decision to remove the entire folder from the content tree and did a publish. That solved it for now, and we're in the process of recreating it on a test environment to see if the error comes back.

We did not remove any versions but we did publish a child element (with two language versions prior to the incident, which seems somehow to have triggered it)
We did have an unscheduled reboot of the machine holding the SQL server so we suspect corruption to have caused it

Comment: Check every notification item and see if it has at least 1 version in `da` language (especially the new child item you added)

Comment: I even tried creating a package with all the items and installing it on another instance, there was no problem there.
All the items have exactly 1 version in `da`